# React js hooks lodash set strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, react-hooks

I use lodash to be able to change the value of an attribute (object, array) to a certain depth, but I'm having a strange behavior.

The situation is this, I use react js with hooks, in the state I have an object that holds the user information, so I do a fetch to load the user information on the object that is in the state called `user`.

However, this information is not saved only in the `user` object but also in another object called `userInfo`, so I have this information that is in the state twice but with a different nominative attribute.

What do I need to have this information twice, only to make sure that when the user wants to change their data (profile page), I check if the data he modified has actually been modified, that is, there is at least one element different from the original one.

The problem where it is, that when I edit a data that is on `user` in turn it changes the same data on`userInfo`, but I don't understand the reason.

The strangest thing that this problem happens to me only on the local project in which I am working making a simple example on codesandbox, the problem does not happen.

The problem seems to be due to the `handleChangeField` function, but I don't understand why only the local happens.

Can you help me out?

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6mnzb)

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import ReactJson from "react-json-view";
import lodash from "lodash";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 200
    }
  }
}));

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    user: {
      name: "James",
      surname: "bond",
      card: {
        id: 7,
        group: "J"
      },
      scope: [{ scope: "user", actions: ["create", "delete"] }]
    },
    userInfo: {
      name: "James",
      surname: "bond",
      card: {
        id: 7,
        group: "J"
      },
      scope: [{ scope: "user", actions: ["create", "delete"] }]
    }
  });

  const handleChangeField = field => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    let newState = lodash.cloneDeep(state);
    lodash.set(newState, field, value);
    console.log(newState, state);
    setState(newState);
  };

  console.log("Change", state);

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <ReactJson
        src={state}
        theme={"solarized"}
        enableClipboard={false}
        displayObjectSize={false}
      />

      <TextField
        id="standard-basic"
        label="Name"
        onChange={handleChangeField("user.name")}
      />
      <TextField
        id="standard-basic"
        label="Group"
        onChange={handleChangeField("user.card.group")}
      />
      <TextField
        id="standard-basic"
        label="Action[0]"
        onChange={handleChangeField("user.scope[0].actions[0]")}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Rather than relying on off-site resources, please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Making your runnable example right here, on-site, helps people help you.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem where it is, that when I edit a data that is on `user` in turn it changes the same data on `userInfo`, but I don't understand the reason.

That tells you that `user` and `userInfo` (or `user.card` and `userInfo.card`) refer to the **same object** in the situation where it's happening:

```js
const userDataFromAjaxOrWhatever = {
    name: "James",
    surname: "bond",
    card: {
      id: 7,
      group: "J"
    },
    scope: [{ scope: "user", actions: ["create", "delete"] }]
};
const state = {
    user: userDataFromAjaxOrWhatever,
    userInfo: userDataFromAjaxOrWhatever
};

console.log(`state.user.name =     ${state.user.name}`);
console.log(`state.userInfo.name = ${state.userInfo.name}`);
console.log("Setting state.user.name = Joe");
state.user.name = "Joe";
console.log(`state.user.name =     ${state.user.name}`);     // Joe
console.log(`state.userInfo.name = ${state.userInfo.name}`); // Joe
```

It doesn't happen with the code you've quoted because `user` and `userInfo` point to different objects. I assume in your real code, you're populating your state in a different way, rather than with hardcoded object literals.

It's impossible to say why you're ending up with `user` and `userInfo` pointing to the same object because you haven't shown us the code where that's happening, but you must be doing something similar to the snippet above where it does:

```
const state = {
    user: userDataFromAjaxOrWhatever,
    userInfo: userDataFromAjaxOrWhatever
};
```

Instead:

```
const state = {
    user: userDataFromAjaxOrWhatever,
    userInfo: lodash.cloneDeep(userDataFromAjaxOrWhatever)
};
```

Then you don't have that problem:

```js
const userDataFromAjaxOrWhatever = {
    name: "James",
    surname: "bond",
    card: {
      id: 7,
      group: "J"
    },
    scope: [{ scope: "user", actions: ["create", "delete"] }]
};
const state = {
    user: userDataFromAjaxOrWhatever,
    userInfo: _.cloneDeep(userDataFromAjaxOrWhatever)
};

console.log(`state.user.name =     ${state.user.name}`);
console.log(`state.userInfo.name = ${state.userInfo.name}`);
console.log("Setting state.user.name = Joe");
state.user.name = "Joe";
console.log(`state.user.name =     ${state.user.name}`);     // Joe
console.log(`state.userInfo.name = ${state.userInfo.name}`); // James
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I still have not been able to solve the problem, doing further tests I am having this problem it would be, I have a function that changes the input field to a certain depth `handleChangeField ('user.name')` the function is this
```const handleChangeField = field => ({target: {value}}) => {
const newState = lodash.cloneDeep (state);
lodash.set (newState, field, value);
setState (newState);
}; ```
Could you tell me if in your opinion it is logically wrong?

Comment: @Paul - Assuming `cloneDeep` does what it says, I don't see a problem there (other than it may be cloning more than it needs to, but that's pretty harmless).